# How to make Umbraco form with validation work correctly?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7, surface-controller

I couldn't find even one tutorial that correctly and fully explains how to make a form with validation.

More specifically I have the following issue - when the errors are passed, the filled content by the user is lost.

I am using Umbraco v7, but I imagine the concept is the same with 8 and 9?!

##### Option 1

Generally, what people do in the tutorials is that there is 1 action `RenderForm` (get) and then another `SubmitForm` (post). From what I get, if validation fails, you have to call `CurrentUmbracoPage()` to basically reload the `.cshtml` page and include this data. This is where the problem come in: the render from is done through an action which usually looks like that:

```
 Html.RenderAction("RenderForm", "Contact", new ViewModel());
```

and thus it resets the data to a new blank Model. I still have the errors, but whatever the user prefilled is now lost. I imagine there must be a way to just pass the model here, but I couldn't find out how.

##### Option 2

An alternative way of dealing with forms is to have only the POST controller action and load the form through a partial in the `.cshtml`:

```
Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Partials/Forms/_ContactUsForm.cshtml", new ViewModel());
```

which brings us to the same problem - errors show but `ViewModel` data is blanked.

I tried calling it without a model, but it throws an error. I would expect you could prepare the model, and then just use it in the `.cshtml` or the partial `.cshmtml` but I wasn't able to find out how.

By `prepare model` I mean that I have to set a bunch of variables, prefill information, set dropdowns etc. before I render form. This should be done in the controller somehow before I load both the blank form and the filled form with errors.

---

##### My research:

The official documentation has no mention of errors:
https://our.umbraco.com/Documentation/Fundamentals/Code/Creating-Forms/index-v7

These tutorials show you how to make forms but again, don't show you how to show data when form is invalid:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3V0A1AYJbys
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LumPhKQvUCQ
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3EF13vcGE18
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vxGG4dWyBEQ

Comment: Probably a good idea to include the umbraco version you are using

Comment: I had a tag with the version - 7, but I added it to the text too

Answer (score 0):

So in my main page I would usually have

@Html.Action("Render", "Form");

This calls the `Render` method on the `FormController`

The render method prepares the form model and then calls the partial

```
var model = new FormViewModel{
    enter instantiation code here as required 
}
return PartialView("~/Views/Partials/Form.cshtml", model);
```

Submitting the form will call the Submit method on the same controller

Usually in your submit method you would have

```
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    return CurrentUmbracoPage();
}
//Depending on your production set up, an option is to use TempData here to 
send some sort of success flag if the form was processed successfully by the backend
TempData.Add("Success", true);
return RedirectToCurrentUmbracoPage();
```

Instead of `RedirectToCurrentUmbracoPage` on success you might prefer to just redirect to a success page, if you have one, with `RedirectToUmbracoPage(pageId)`

Assuming you know how to set up the form model in mvc with required attributes etc as the ModelState.IsValid will rely on those for validation.

How is your partial set up by the way, are you using BeginUmbracoForm

```
using (Html.BeginUmbracoForm<FormController>("Submit", null, new
    {
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I understand your logic, and that was my understanding too. The only problem is in the template where you have ` new {...}`. This basically deletes the data user already wrote before the validation and he has to start filling the whole form from scratch.

Comment: That's not what happens with my implementation.  If you return CurrentUmbracoPage() this should populate the form from ModelState.

Comment: Can you confirm you are returning CurrentUmbracoPage if the form is not valid?

Comment: I can definitely confirm that

Comment: Maybe you could post the full code (or a cut down version) for your Umbraco page, form partial, model and controller.